# Virgo SuperCluster and space time

Tags: cosmology

Is the Virgo Supercluster affected at all by the expansion of space? What about the larger filament that Virgo resides in?I don't quite understand how gravity affects space time locally in groups of galaxies, and am wondering if the expansion of space is lumpy. It would be nice to know we are not all being stretched... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you define the limits of the Virgo Supercluster, it is (probably) not a gravitationally bound object and the Hubble expansion will (probably) eventually pull it apart. The Virgo Cluster is typically taken as the centre of the Supercluster, and if you look at the [recessional velocities of the galaxies in the Virgo Cluster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgo_Cluster#Bright_or_notable_galaxies_of_the_Virgo_Cluster) they are mostly receding from us at around 1000 km/s (within an order of magnitude). I'm not sure if it's known for certain whether the Milky Way (or the Local Group) is gravitationally bound to the Virgo Supercluster but I believe the evidence is that it's not.

It would be interesting to know how much the mass in the Supercluster decreases the expected Hubble velocity. The expected recessional velocity is just given by $v = H_0D$, and with $H_0$ around 70 (km/s)/Mpc and the centre of the Virgo Cluster at 16.5 Mpc we'd expect a recessional velocity for the Virgo Cluster of 1,150 km/sec. This is about the order of magnitude of the observed recessional velocities, but the trouble is that the velocities of the galaxies that make it up are widely scattered. I don't know if anyone has managed to obtain a meaningful average recessional velocity for the Virgo Cluster. I have found [this article](http://cosmology.berkeley.edu/Education/Essays/superclusters.html) that claims the observed recession is about 10% smaller than expected from Hubble's law. Even though the article is on a respected web site (Berkeley) it gives no detail or references so I'd take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation using Hubble's constant. Do you have some simple equation that relates space-time to gravity? I'm not an astronomer at all, but it's all interesting stuff.

Comment: Not simple, no. The expansion of spacetime is described by the FLRW metric. Searching this site for it will find lots of related questions and answers (many from me :-) but I wouldn't describe any of them as *simple*.